# In English, is the use of the -ing participle verb form as adjectives or subjects or objects an example of conversion (a.k.a. zero-derivation)?

Tags: syntax, morphology, morphosyntax, participles

This is a pretty straight forward question. But here are some examples:

> 1. Baking is my hobby. (used as a subject thing, or as some would call it, a gerund or verbal noun)
> 2. I will be a contestant in the baking competition. (as an adjective in a compound noun phrase)
> 3. I enjoy baking. (as an object complement thing)
> 4. I prefer cooking over baking. (as a prepositional object)

I've added an answer below and put a bounty on this question because I want to get some more feedback, particularly regarding my answer.

Comment: _Conversion_ and _zero-derivation_ are two terms for the same phenomenon. So the answer to your question is "Yes".

Comment: @jlawler - Ok, I appreciate you attention, "Yes" in quotes, which leads me to believe there may be some qualification. In this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235944115_Zero-derivation_-_Functional_Change_-_Metonymy - the author never once mentions gerunds or participles as subject to conversion. My actual interest in in learning when a 'gerund' becomes a non-finite clause, where in such a clause it can't be considered a gerund, when it takes a verb complement. Also curious to know how you define 'gerund' since there doesn't seem to be a widely accepted definition of the term.

Comment: What in the world do you mean by "when"? Are you talking about a stage in a derivation, a historical event, or a set of contexts? BTW, the _Yes_ was in quotes because it was likely not an intended answer -- I heard the question as asking for a distinction between the two, and there is none.

Comment: @jlawler, there is another answer which is consistent with the equivalence of *conversion* and *zero-derivation*.  That is: "No".  (There is no reason to think that -ing gerunds are derived from -ing participles.)

Comment: Have we been discussing derivations? I'm still confused about the _when_.

Comment: @jlawler - You're right, that was poorly phrased. I intended 'or' as inclusive and my use of 'when' is equally confusing. What seems clear is that present participles seem very noun like at times, particularly when they are used as subjects or objects, especially if they take adjectives and are used without complements, and much more verb like  (and perhaps) clause like, when used with complements. My question (I think) is when participles take complements, are the correctly parsed as non-finite clauses? But that is another question, for another time.

Comment: In some cases you can tell when an _-ing_ word is a verb (the default situation, since it's a verb form), and when it's an adjective or a noun. If it takes an article, for instance, it's a noun; if it takes a direct object, it's a verb; if it directly precedes the noun it modifies without any other appendages, it can be treated as an adjective. But whether it actually **IS** an adjective, or a noun, or a verb, just can't be determined in many cases. Think of it as Schrödinger's Participle; its actual form is indeterminate until someone says it; then it's whatever they think it is.

Comment: Re: conversion you may want to take a look at https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1671/445

Answer (score 2):

None of your examples has a present participle.  All the examples have gerunds or, in other words, Poss-ing nominalizations: a sentence with the verb "bake" has been converted into a noun phrase.  This would be more obvious if you supplied your examples with a subject or object for "bake": "Joyce enjoys my baking cookies for her."

Comment: While "my baking cookies for her" is a NP, isn't "baking" in it still a verb as it has an object?

Comment: @curiousdannii How can "baking cookies for her" be an NP. "Baking" has "cookies" as direct object and hence must be a verb (nouns don't take direct objects). I think "baking" in the OP's first example is strictly speaking ambiguous, though noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in "occasional baking is my hobby". Similarly in the OP's third example: verb preferred but noun can't be ruled out.

Comment: @curiousdannii, yes, "baking" is still a verb.  Gerunds are verbs.  The entire sentence "I bake cookies for her" is converted to a NP, but within the nominalization, "baking" remains a verb with a direct object.

Comment: @GregLee Surely "baking" in the OP's first example is ambiguous? It could be a verb (thus a clause) or an NP, as I mentioned above.

Comment: @BillJ, That's not quite right.  Since "baking" is a verb, it cannot be modified by an adjective -- only by an adverb: "my occasionally baking cookies for her".  Your example "occasional baking (*cookies) is my hobby" does not have a gerund, but rather has a derived noun "baking" which, confusingly, uses the same -ing suffix (which is why it won't take a direct object).  I'm not sure about the ambiguity of examples 1 and 3.

Comment: Slight misunderstanding: I'm saying that in 1, 3 and 4 "baking" could be a verb or a noun, and hence is ambiguous. In 1 for example, it would be a verb in "Baking cookies is my hobby", and a noun in "Occasional baking is my hobby". 3 is even clearer: a verb in "I enjoy baking cookies", and a noun in "I enjoy occasional baking". The potential for different dependents gives rise to the ambiguity.

Comment: @BillJ, well, maybe.  But note the unacceptability of *"Occasional baking of cookies is my hobby", which needs a "the".

Comment: Ambiguity arises in terms of PoS but not in terms of meaning. The term gerund seems to have gained such broad scope that it has become almost, if not entirely useless. It suffices, I suppose, for those who settle on this use of the participle as derived to a noun (or adjective, I guess). But if a gerund is a noun, then it should not take verb complements. By my (rather dull) lights it seems that the distinction doesn't occur at the word or word phrase level - it happens at the sentence phrase level. It seems to me that these are present participles taking the role of subjects, objects...

Comment: ...(of a verb or preposition) or adjectives in a noun phrase (ok, that's a word level distinction). In terms of parsing why can't we just say that these are non-finite verbs that function as subjects or objects in sentences, or as adjectives in noun phrases? This would obviate the need to determine if they are more or less like verbs or nouns. They're just verb phrases that can take a variety of roles in sentences, much like noun phrases can be used adverbially such as in, 'I saw her last week'.

Comment: @UbuEnglish, what you've said in these two comments is partially correct.  For one thing, it's true that gerunds are non-finite verbs, and it is true that other parts of the verb phrase besides just the verb may be involved.  Aside from the ending -ing, I don't any connection with participles.  Participles are modifiers.  Nominalized sentences are arguments.  That's an important difference.

Comment: @GregLee -  Ok, it's going to take me some time to digest this but a couple of things that strike me are 1) that using the term gerund in this way seems to be raising it to a PoS, while others have decided to drop it all together, and 2) 'participles are modifiers' may account for their use in some subordinate non-finite clauses and as adjectives, but not for their use in the continuous tenses. I'm getting my head around nominals and nominalization, which seem to apply only to word morphology, so your term nominalized sentences is confusing - could you explain this?

Comment: Your 1) is false. (I use gerund to mean the -ing form of a verb used in nominalizations -- it does not need to be a part of speech.) Your 2) does not give any reason to make the -ing form in the progressive aspect an argument, surely, and it does become a modifier through relative clause reduction ("the sleeping child").

Comment: @GregLee Sleeping in "the sleeping child" is undergoing conversion because it is used in a noun phrase. It is not a reduced relative clause because 'sleeping' in not a verb (it's an adjective). The clause, "the child who is sleeping" may have the same meaning but is an entirely different grammatical structure - it does not reduce to a noun phrase - it reduces to 'the child, sleeping...".

Comment: "the child who is sleeping" is already a noun phrase.  It is not a clause.

Comment: @GregLee : well, *who is sleeping* is a finite subordinate clause, *the child" is its subject, which is a noun phrase. I would argue, at least in terms of language instruction, that the whole construction is not best described as a noun phrase but rather a subject or object phrase of the form np+clause. I understand that your calling this a noun phrase is the result of phrase tree analysis that groups constituents hierarchically. But this approach requires a level of sophistication that is beyond what most ordinary students, particularly ESL learners, are able to get their heads around.

Comment: So, I am attempting to create an instructional grammar that is reduced in its linguistic complexity but still adequate to teach students how to use English grammatically. In my experience it is much easier for students to focus on sentence phrase relations and the word phrase relations that exist in and between them. This approach allows me to reduce the terms and concepts used, so most constructions can be explained in terms of the complementary syntax between word phrases and their relations, which are generally descriptive, adverbial or objectival. Did you read my answer below?

Comment: @GregLee: I agree with you that these are not present participles, but only technically. This term seems to only apply when the form is used in the continuous tenses but it has other uses and is better called an -ing participle in any case. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a linguist, so please forgive any apparent presumption on my part in venturing an answer here. I'm confident about what I'm saying but more interested in the discussion of this answer with experts, than I am in finding agreement.

Conversion seems to apply only to morphological changes to a word's base form through affixation, or zero-derivation where the base form is just used as a different PoS, for example *run* in *I run," (verb), and *I had a good run,* (noun). But the PoS designation can only be made once a word is functioning in a sentence. Otherwise, it is not possible to say that a word like *run*, alone in its base form, has any part of speech, unless it only functions as a single part of speech, like the noun *car* or the verb *teach*, which have very narrow functional scope - car is always a noun and teach is always a verb. There cannot be any conversion when a word such as *run* is used as a noun, it is simply a word that con function as either a noun or a verb.

The -ing participle is a morphological form of its base word which is always a verb. The -ing participle has not undergone conversion unless it is used as a different part of speech from its base, in other words, when it is used as an adjective or noun in a noun phrase. Otherwise, it can be used in the progressive aspect of finite verb phrases or in non-finite verb phrases, or used as a bare participle as a subject or object. In the latter case as a bare participle it derives it's thingness from being used as a subject or object but it is still simply a verb form.

I just don't see any reason to say there is conversion when bare -ing participles are used as subjects or objects. If one were to assert that conversion does indeed happen at the sentence phrase level, then we would have to say that clauses used as subjects or objects also undergo conversion and become nouns. I know that some folks do say this, e.g. the noun clause (aka content clause). In all of these cases (bare participles and relative clauses as subjects or objects) calling them anything but verb forms or clauses, is designating these forms as a PoS (noun) which they are not. They are verbs or clauses as subjects or objects. To do so confuses sentence level roles and their S|V|C relations with PoS designations. Subjects and objects are always things but they are not always nouns, and just because a verb from or clause can take these sentence level roles does not render them nouns.

I think the only true example of conversion is in sentence number 2.

> I will be a contestant in the baking competition. (as an adjective in
> a compound noun phrase)

Because the participle form is used in the adjective position in a noun phrase it converts from participle to adjective and in doing so it loses its ability behave like a verb - it cannot be modified as a verb any more - no adverbial or object relations. I don't think present participle adjectives can even take a qualifying adverb as a modifier, as many base adjectives can.

Conversion (nominalization) would also happen for present participles used in the noun position in a noun phrase:

> some difficult *programming*
>
> a very old *building*,
>
> the *training*

All of these verb forms are nominalized by the constraint of the noun phrase structure they are used in and they lose their ability to function as verbs. But -ing participles used subjects and objects without such noun phrase constraints can still take adverbial complements and direct objects in ways that participles used in noun phrases cannot.

Otherwise, participles used alone as a subject or object derive their thingness from the role they play as subject or object, not through conversion. They can only be identified as a verb phrase because they are verb forms and as word phrases have none of the structural elements of a noun phrase; no determiners, adjectives, and no nouns. The only thing they have in common with nouns is their thingness, which is inherited from their syntactical role as subject or object, but in terms of word class or PoS, they can only be identified as verbs.

Subjects and objects are always things but they are roles in sentences that can be played by different types of word phrases; noun phrases, verb phrases (participles and infinitives) and even clauses can function as subjects and objects.

Comment: You're paying too much attention to "conversion". That's not a terribly useful term, and it can be defined in ways that include or exclude whatever one chooses. If you or somebody else wants to call situation X "conversion" but not situation Y, that's fine. Nobody cares unless you use the term to justify something that's not defined by it.

Comment: On reading it again, I also think you're paying too much attention to PoS. In English, especially, where morphology is almost unimportant, part of speech is as much a matter of opinion as anything else. The important thing for a grammar learner is constituents. Learn to recognize the constituents of a sentence and the parts of speech become either obvious or irrelevant: In _Going to the store is fun for him_, _going to the store_ is the subject and therefore a noun phrase (as well as a gerund clause); and you can call _up_ in _Call him up now_ anything you like and it'll still behave the same.

Comment: Thanks @jlawler - I need to dig into constituent grammar more, but my first take away is that it's a bit confusing with so many tests delivering diferent results - it's seems that everything is a constituent of something (or not) depending on how you test it, and also that as a syntactic analysis constituency seems very much tied to semantic dependencies. My objective is to simplify concepts for ESL learners as much as possible and somehow, when I dig into such complexity, I manage to come away with an understanding that allows me to do that.

Comment: If that's your goal, you need a fairly integrated approach. I recommend McCawley's; [his grammar](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Syntactic_Phenomena_of_English.html) covers everything important, and it was written and revised by one person. Who knew everything, more or less. It's thick, but it repays careful investigation and it's very clear.

Comment: @jlawler : I do need an integrated approach, particularly where it comes to terminology, and of course one that focuses on essential concepts. But what I'm finding is that tradittional grammar (all of it) is quite inconsistent in its use of terms and concepts and that while linguists are much more consistent with thier respective linguistic idolects (which is a feat in itself), there is still broad variance in how similar terms are appled. So, I am defining a well integrated set of terms and concepts that are particularly useful to ESL students, which is a challenge but one I'm well along.

Comment: Also: Linguistics and language learning have very different goals but traditional language learning seems overly dependent on concepts developed to explain how the phenomena of language exists and works. That complexity of analysis makes a lot of sense in the linguistic domain but language learning is intuitive and I think reducing complexity and letting the brain do its thing (processing language subconsciously) serves the interests of ESL learners. Thanks for the recommendation - it's very interesting.

Comment: A lot depends on the language(s) of the students. If they all speak one language, it's going to affect their English in specific ways; but if they're various -- the way my classes were when I taught ESL in the US -- then you have to be general in the way you describe things, and consistency is key. But you're right, there is none in ESL; every textbook writer uses their own terminology and their own metaphors. And they're often wrong and confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Historically it's the other way around.  English lost its original active participle and replaced it with the construction *on doing* (with the gerund), which eroded to *a-doing* and then *doing*.

Comment: This should be added as a comment. It is interesting how etymology plays into this question. There's an article related to this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ing